# Special characters in HTML

Tags: html, vb.net, special-characters

I am trying to retrieve specific information from a European web site. Now, the problem is I am often facing strings containing special characters such as "ä". When I try to write same into a text file it is coming as "�a". How to avoid this? My code is in VB.Net. There are no html codes for special characters in the response.

TIA!

Comment: Make sure you use the right encoding. If your string is wrong, try changing the encoding for reading the web. If your file is wrong, try changing the encoding for writing the file. I had a similar problem with french I had to use UTF7 or UTF8 (can't remember).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried using WebBrowser instead of HttpRequest and Its working.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should be able to do this by using the appropriate character coding for UTF-8 (which is what I assume you are trying to convert to)

Here is a [list of HTML Codes](http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm).

Looks like the one you are wanting is:

```
Character   Friendly Code   Numerical Code  Hex Code    Description
ä           &auml;           &#228;         &#xE4;          Lowercase A-umlaut
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am not getting html code in the response. Its just a literal character without any html codes. I could have used WebUtility.htmldecode to obtain correct value if that the case.